# Does .NET support Windows Eventing 6.0?

Tags: .net, windows, manifest, event-log, instrumentation

I want to use the Windows Eventing 6 API from a C# application to log messages to a specific channel in Windows Server 2008 event log. There is a good example on how to use it but it's only C++. In the example it's mentioned that .NET doesn't support Windows Eventing 6. There are 2 examples in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163431.aspx , http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa382690(VS.85).aspx

My question is how to do it in C# or do you know if there is a .Net support for this API.

Answer (score 2):

I think you ask about ETW stuff.

Check:

[Writing events with System.Diagnostics.Eventing](http://www.atrevido.net/blog/2008/02/28/Writing+Events+With+SystemDiagnosticsEventing.aspx)

> ... or, how the hell to use Vista and 2008's new ETW stuff with managed code. And, introducing ecmanaged: A decent way to do all this stuff.

and some more info:

[.NET Event Tracing for Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/dixi/net-event-tracing-for-windows), [Naveen's Blog ETW Series](https://web.archive.org/web/20150518012123/http://naveensrinivasan.com:80/etw/) (specificly [Using .NET 4.0 Event Tracing for Windows (ETW) along with application ETW](https://web.archive.org/web/20150720015101/http://naveensrinivasan.com:80/2010/03/17/using-clr-4-0-event-tracing-for-windows-etw-along-with-application-etw/)), [ETW Events in the .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee517330(v=VS.100).aspx), [TraceEvent](https://web.archive.org/web/20170601043145/http://bcl.codeplex.com:80/wikipage?title=TraceEvent)

Also some info about regular event logging in case you interested too:
[EventLog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.eventlog?view=net-5.0), [EventLogInstaller](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.eventloginstaller?view=netframework-4.8). Example: [Event Logging](http://www.roque-patrick.com/windows/final/bbl0134.html)